# How to add Mutiple Error Outputs in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am implementing as SSIS where I do one to one mapping from source DB to Destination DB for set of tables in sequence.
So what I need is when mapping happens if any row failed to map, particular Id of the row must store in a separate common table with table name which was processing in order to handle manually.
Ex. If two tables failed, common table should have the failed rows with Id and table name.

I could not find a solution for this?

What I was trying to do was add Id of failed row to Common table and add flat file to each error output of tables.
But cannot add two error outputs to DB and flat file.

Is there a way to handle this scenario?

Comment: You could try to use a conditional split on your error output in order to redirect the rows to the corresponding destinations.

Answer (score 0):

1.Please drag the red line and edit **error output** in OLEDB Source.

[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uJsM.jpg)

[Error Redirect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuliV.jpg)

2.Add a new **variable** to store sql table name.

[Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkC4z.jpg)

3.Drag **Derived Column** and add new column TableName.

[Derived Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfaxg.jpg)

The following links will be helpful:

***[Lesson 4-3: Add error flow redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/lesson-4-3-adding-error-flow-redirection?view=sql-server-ver15)***

***[An overview of Error Handling in SSIS packages](https://www.sqlshack.com/an-overview-of-error-handling-in-ssis-package/)***